# Program with Python that can read from a file, need to output number of character after line1 and recurrence of a character

Tags: python

It is the first time that I work with Python and I have little experience with programming in general. I have to build a program with Python that can read from a file, need to output number of character after line1 and number of recurrence of a characters. I'm struggling and don't know how to count single characters of a file. I have to find the recurrence of 'C' and 'G' in a file but I haven't got any clues.
This is what I have done:

```
while True:
    try:    
        filename = raw_input('Enter file:')

        filename = open(filename, "r+")

        line1 = filename.readline()
        num_lines = 0
        num_words = 0
        num_chars = 0
        len_line1 = len  (line1)

        for line in filename:
            words = line.split()

            num_lines += 1
            num_words += len(words)
            num_chars += len(line)

    except:
        break

print "Output is : ", line1

print "Length : ", num_chars - len_line1

print filename.split().index('C')
```

Comment: Indent with 4 spaces. Do not indent with tabs.

Comment: Please do not use `except:` without printing some information about the exception http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info

Answer (score 1):

You have most of what you need already. Nice work!

For counting the occurrences of `c`s and `g`s, remember that a line can be iterated over.
Say we had a couple of variables `num_c` and `num_g`.
Then we could loop over each line incrementing these variables when we encountered one of those two letters.

Below is an attempt, but it's not exactly the same as yours.
So fix yours instead.  Good luck!

```
with open('/path/to/the/file.txt','r') as fin:
    num_chars = 0
    num_lines = 0
    num_words = 0
    num_c = 0
    num_g = 0
    fin.next()
    for line in fin:
        num_lines += 1
        num_words += len(line.split())
        for char in line:
            num_chars += 1
            if char.lower() == 'c':
                num_c += 1
            elif char.lower() == 'g':
                num_g += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to extend this you might find it easier to store the counts in a data structure so you don't keep adding lines and lines of if statements, checking each character for ones that you're interested in

To build on bernie's example,

```
from collections import defaultdict

with open('/path/to/the/file.txt','r') as fin:
    num_chars= 0
    character_dict= defaultdict(int)
    fin.next()
    for line in fin:
        num_chars += len(line)
        for char in line:
            character_dict[char] += 1
            # if you dont want to count upper and lower case letters seperately then use the following line instead
            #character_dict[char.upper()] += 1

print "There are %i 'G's" %character_dict["G"]
print "There are %i 'C's" %character_dict["C"]
```